# Rack-O card Game for 2 players Using Python

Tags: python, spyder, card

It goes fine while it's 1st players turn but when it comes to the 2nd player, program stops.
Also how do i make the program guess the winner? We are covering function now and I'm not sure how to write it.

```
import random


def main():
   # displays the intro
   intro()
   # assigns and shuffles the deck
   deck = [x for x in range(1, 61)]
   random.shuffle(deck)
  # asks for the size of the rack
   rack_size = int(input('Enter the size of the rack to use. '
                                'Must be between 5 and 10: '))
   print()
  # starts the discard pile after passing out the needed cards for a rack
   discard = deck[rack_size * 2]
  # the deck top card after starting discard pile
   new_card = deck[rack_size * 2 + 1]
  # assigns the players hands
   player_rack1, player_rack2 = get_rack(deck, rack_size)
  # allows players to pick and change cards
   place_card(player_rack1, player_rack2, new_card, discard)
  
def instructions():
 # prints the instructions of the game
    print()
    print('The goal of the game is to get the cards in your rack of cards')
    print('into ascending order. Your rack has ten slots numbered 1 to 10.')
    print('During your turn you can draw the top card of the deck or take')
    print('the top card of the discard pile.')
    print('If you draw the top card of the deck, you can use that card to')
    print('replace a card in one slot of your rack. The replaced card '
 'goes to')
    print('the discard pile.')
    print('Alternatively you can simply choose to discard the drawn card.')
    print('If you take the top card of the discard pile you must use it to')
    print('replace a card in one slot of your rack. The replaced card goes')
    print('to the top of the discard pile.')
    print()

def intro():
 # displays the introduction for the game
    print('----- Welcome to Rack - O! -----')
    display = input('Enter y to display instructions: ')
 # displays instructions is user wants to see them
    if display == 'Y' or display == 'y':
        instructions()
    else:
        print()
 # asks user for the seed and sets the seed
    seed = int(input('Enter number for initial seed: '))
    random.seed(seed)

def get_rack(cards, hand):
 # assigns the shuffled cards to the player racks
    player_one_hand = cards[:hand]
    player_two_hand = cards[hand:hand * 2]
    return player_one_hand, player_two_hand

def take_turn(throw, player_hand):
 
    player = 1
    while player <= 2:
        print('Player', player, 'turn.')
        print('Your current rack', player_hand)
        print('Top of discard pile', throw)
        choice = input('Enter d to draw anything else to take '
                       'top of discard pile: ')
        print()
        player += 1
        throw = player_hand[0]
        return choice

def place_card(player_hand1, player_hand2, new, throw):
 # if the user take the card from the discard pile
    if take_turn(throw, player_hand1) != 'd':
        print('Enter the card number to replace with the', throw, ': ', end='')
        choice = int(input())
        # error checks if the user picks a card that is not in their rack
        while choice not in player_hand1:
            print(choice, 'is not is your rack.')
            print('Enter the card number to replace with the', throw, ': ', end='')
            choice = int(input())
 # replaces and assigns the card they replaced to the rack
        else:
           index = player_hand1.index(choice)
           player_hand1.remove(choice)
           player_hand1.insert(index, throw)
           print('The rack after the turn', player_hand1), print()
           take_turn(throw, player_hand2)
 # if the player doesn't take from the discard pile
    else:
      print('drew the', new[0])
      new_choice = input('Enter p to place card, anything else to discard it: ')
      if new_choice == 'p':
          print('Enter the card number to replace with the', new[0], ': ',
end='')
          choose = int(input())
          index = player_hand2.index(choose)
          player_hand2.remove(choose)
          player_hand2.insert(index, new[0])
          print('The rack after the turn', player_hand2)
main()
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpIuS.png)

P.S. my major is Journalism so Python is not exactly my thing, so I apologize if this question is dumb.

Comment: The while loop in take_turn will only ever run once because of the *return* - i.e., it will never prompt for player 2 input

Comment: thank you so much! now i only need to figure out how to find a winner :)